# MODX Revolution get value of MIGX TV from another resource

Tags: modx-revolution, migx

I have a resource that gets data from a MIGX TV in the following chunk

```
<ul id="testimonialsSlider">

        <li>
            <div>
            <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i><p>[[+text]]</p><i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
            </div>

            <p>[[+name]]</p>
            <p>[[+source]]</p>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

and I want to use that data on yet another resource. How do I get those three TVs? Via getResources?

Comment: Have you asked this on forum? The author is in there everyday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Snippet that comes with the MIGX Extra, called "getImageList", accepts a property that tells it which MODX Resource from which to query the MIGX TV. An example of such a snippet call might be:

```
[[getImageList?
    &tvname=`myMIGXtv`
    &tpl=`testimonialsSliderItem`
    &docid=`5`
]]
```

That would get the content of the TV named `myMIGXtv` from the MODX Resource with ID of `5`, and format the output using the Chunk named `testimonialsSliderItem`.

Assuming your MIGX TV is configured with fields that have the keys: `text`, `name`, and `source`, AND the Resource ID `5` has the values you want, in those fields in the MIGX TV named `myMIGXtv`, AND your example Chunk is named `testimonialsSliderItem`...then the example above should work verbatim.